# SAML Attribute Mapping for Aws Cognito - Signup or Signin works but not both

Tags: saml-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-workspace

I have setup my GSuite account as a SAML iDP for Cognito User Pools (not identity pools).

If i provide no attribute mappings a new user trying to signup via GSuite login gets the following error.

> Error in SAML response processing: Invalid user attributes: email: Attribute is required.

However if I add an email mapping, the user can signup. But can't ever sign in again as they get this error (strange as email is writable by this app client)

> Error in SAML response processing: Invalid user attributes: email: Attribute cannot be updated.

Ideas as to whats going on?

In browser, using Hosted UI.

Comment: `email: Attribute required` might indicate a wrong attribute mapping. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153956/3703307

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out I had made the email address immutable during CloudFormation setup. Even though the email is not being modified, it needs to be mutable.

You can determine the mutability of email via the following command.

```
 aws --output table cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id <user pool id>  | grep -B6 -A7 "  |  email  "
```

Comment: How do you change the email to mutable?

Comment: You have to create a new user-pool

Comment: @AdamMills using Cognito user pool, there is no option to make default attributes mutable. Only  custom attributes have option to be mutable.

Comment: In my case, the attribute email was immutable because it was so inadvertently defined by me in CloudFormation YAML :
    SomeUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
        Schema:
          - Name: email
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: false
            Required: true

. Should be Mutable: true

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is facing this issue when using SAML and AD as the identity provider, you have to configure Attribute Mapping.

[image]

Go to Attribute Mapping under Federation, Enter `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` for SAML attribute and Select Email fro User pool attribute

Answer (score 2):

I had the error below randomly after being able to login the first time.  Disabling and then deleting the user from the pool and allowing Cognito to recreate it fixed the issue for me.  I assume there is an AWS bug here somewhere.

> Error in SAML response processing: Invalid user attributes: email: Attribute cannot be updated.